# Printing a Word Doc or a PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, ms-word, interop

My program takes a word doc and manipulates it with the Codeplex DocX open source app.  That works great.

Now I need to print it. I've looked for a few hours and I haven't found a good way to print the PDF version of the file. I even tried to use AcroRd32.exe and it's just plain clunky and not really usable for a serious application.

I do have it printing with the Word.Interop but that is tying me down to a specific version of Word, more specifically, the version I have on my machine. That makes the lower versions that our customers use not work and the devs cannot compile if they aren't on 2010.

I need a way to print either a pdf or a word doc (2003 or greater) seamlessly without being prompted with each document like Acrobat Reader is doing.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: if you are in unix you can use command `pdfinfo`

Comment: Codeplex DocX and Word are Microsoft based. I'm coding in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the following library for printing PDFs in past projects:

http://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-library/

They have a free and professional (commercial) version.  It's a great library and well worth the minor expense.

Comment: A similar question I answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006490/printing-a-pdf-from-a-windows-service/1007343#1007343